# Within Apache Ant I would like to replace a string within a file but only for a particular occurence of the string

Tags: ant

Within Apache Ant I would like to replace a string within a file but only for a particular occurence of the string.  I have a for loop that I would like to replace only the loop number occurrence (first loop find the first occurence, second loop find the second string occurence ) with it's associated for loops param value.

```
<exec executable="${postgres-bin-dir}/psql" outputproperty="update-primary-keys-values-@table">
   <arg line="-A -t --host ${source-target-comparison-hostname} --port 5432 --username 'postgres' -d ${source-target-comparison-databasename} -c &quot;array_to_string(ARRAY(select ${primary-keys-@{table}} from stage.@{table} t where t not in (select t from public.@{table} t) and t.${primary-keys-@{table}} not in (select ${primary-keys-@{table}} from stage.@{table} where ${primary-keys-@{table}} not in (select ${primary-keys-@{table}} from public.@{table})) order by ${primary-keys-@{table}}), ',')&quot;"/>
</exec>

<for list="${update-primary-keys-values-@table}" param="keys-values">
    <replace file="${updates-dir}/updates@{table}.sql" token=");" value=") WHERE ${primary-keys-@{table}} = @{keys-values};"/>
</for>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but if you replace the first occurence on the first loop iteration, won't that mean that on the second iteration, what was previously the second occurence will now be the first?

Comment: Yes you are right!!!  I don't know how I missing that.